# Is it possible to automatically download the current pricing matrix from iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Is it possible to automatically download the current pricing matrix from iTunes connect?

I'm talking about the table of pricing tiers that shows you their value in various currencies.  You can see it on the iTunes connect site when you're selecting a pricing tier for an app (or in app purchase).

Aside from manually copy and pasting from iTunes connect, or writing my own scraping code, is there an existing solution to get the most recent version of that table in a form that I can work with from code?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I need a way to programmatically access the pricing matrix.

Comment: I never found a solution but here is the current (as of March 10, 2013) matrix in JSON format.  I spent a couple hours generating this and triple checking it for accuracy.  http://pastebin.com/tLHu5yui

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Discovered [here](https://github.com/affinitas/Apple-Price-Tier-Matrix-JSON/issues/1)

Log in to iTunes Connect and then visit this link, replacing [app-id] with an id from one of your apps.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/[app-id]/pricing/matrix

This is not an official public API and may change, but it is currently working.

Comment: Happy times! Thanks for tracking that down. I had given up all hope.  Fingers crossed this stays public.

Comment: @Codiak I just tried this and it's working fine. Did you replace the `app-id`?

Comment: Yep, it seems it was just broken for a day or so (interestingly on a day there was an update to the matrix).  Now it is working properly again.

Comment: Anyone know if there is a JSON but for the auto-renewable subscriptions matrix?